# ¿como dar prioridad a mi estilo?

Tags: css, reactjs

Estoy utilizando un menú dentro de un [layout de ant](https://ant.design/components/layout/) el cual claro ya trae su estilo y configuración, quiero aplicarle algunos cambios propios de estilos, pero no los respeta, al no ser experto en el tema de **css** no se cual sea la forma mas recomendable de realizar esos cambios.

yo utilice lo siguiente para hacer los cambios, Funciona pero sera muy molesto poner `!important` en todas las lineas que mas adelante quiera editar.

```
li {
    height: 60px !important;
    line-height: 20px !important;
    overflow: inherit !important;
    white-space: unset !important;   
}
```

Donde lo utilizo es en `SiderMenu`

```
const SiderMenu = () => {
    return (
        <Sider
            style={{
                overflow: 'auto',
                height: '100vh',
                position: 'fixed',
                left: 0,
            }}
        >
            <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['4']}>
                {declaraciones.declaraciones.map((e) => (
                    <Menu.Item>
                        <Tooltip title={e}>
                            {e}
                        </Tooltip>
                    </Menu.Item>
                ))}

            </Menu>
        </Sider>
    );
}
```

El cual es llamado en `HomePage` dentro de un `Layout` componente de [Ant Design](https://ant.design/index-cn)

```
const HomePage = () => {


    return (
        <Layout>
            <SiderMenu />
            <Layout className="site-layout" style={{ marginLeft: 200 }}>
                <Header className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 0 }} />
                <Content style={{ margin: '24px 16px 0', overflow: 'initial' }}>
                    <div className="site-layout-background" style={{ padding: 24, textAlign: 'center' }}>

                    <CardSucursal />
                     <Button >Terminar</Button>
        </div>
                </Content>
                <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED</Footer>
            </Layout>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Existe alguna otra forma de poder colocar mi configuración de estilos a los elementos ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basándome lo descrito sobre [Especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#la_excepci%C3%B3n_!important).

> **En lugar de usar `!important`, considera:**
>
> 1. Hacer un mejor uso de las propiedades en cascada de CSS.
> 2. Usar reglas más específicas. Indicando uno o más elementos antes del elemento que estás seleccionando, la regla se vuelve más
>    específica y gana mayor prioridad

Por lo tanto unicamente agregue un **id** al componente `Menu.Item` que esta dentro del `Slider`, quedando así

```
<Menu.Item id='menuItem'>
    <Tooltip title={e}>
        {e}
    </Tooltip>
</Menu.Item>
```

y el código de mi **CSS** de esta forma

```
#menuItem {
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: inherit;
    white-space: unset;   
}
```